# Setting up of git with github

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie to git. I have a question for you.

We 4 people are working on a php project . It is hosted at linux vps server. Currently we are downloading files directly from server and make changes and upload back using FTP.

How we will set up git in this environment.

Comment: You have a setup that is working for you. Why do you need to add `git` here? Is there some problem you are trying to solve with it?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to github, choose the plan you need (I guess you need private repository). I think you should also [create organization](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/creating-organizations/).

Then you create repository and follow the steps described there. The easiest would just just to run

```
git clone your_repository
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup a private git server to manage your change, you can follow this tutorial :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps

If you only have 4 people, you can use github (https://github.com) with private repo. It is the most convenient way to control your code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). This book explains how Git works and is available in many languages.

Chapter 4 explains about Git on a server and setting up your own remote repositories. However, this is complex to set up and like k0ner explains you might want to use GitHub. This is a public Git hosting site. It is by far not the only one, check the Pro Git book chapter 4.9 for a link to an extensive link.

In our company, we use a paid plan with GitHub and our repositories are private. First, we read the Pro Git book to understand how Git works. Next, we searched online for how other people use Git, specifically, what workflow do they use. An example is [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), or check how Atlas uses Git. Based on this research, our code and our future goals we decided on repositories and a public hosting site (GitHub). We are using Git and GitHub happily now.

ps I do not have enough rep to post more links, apologies.